# I'm tired of my lover. How can I break up with them and get a new one?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just wanted to know how can I break up with someone? With Spec. Treynor in particular. I want to try another one, but it seems impossible when I have someone else. For example I got Liara to the cabin with the time-capsule, but where a guide says to say I "want to be more than friends", I don't have that option and Liara only leaves the cabin after a few dialog choices...

Comment: Has Shepard finally gotten his trouser snake in check? I'm impressed. Don't recall seeing any options to break up with a romantic interest in ME3. In ME2 you could dump them at almost any time.

Comment: Well, if there's a relationship with Specialist Traynor in the offing, there *is* no trouser snake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [a Gamefront guide](http://www.gamefront.com/mass-effect-3-how-to-romance-traynor-cortez/)

> NOTE: All serious relationships are final! You can only have one romantic relationship. Entering one will nullify others.

It seems like you confirmed this yourself with a missing dialog option.

Comment: Damn. I knew there was an option missing, but was hoping I could get it back. This is too bad, forcing players to re-play the game to try out all the possibilities? Bad move, Bioware :/

Comment: `This is too bad, forcing players to re-play the game to try out all the possibilities?` This comment seems really funny, given how many different ways the game plays out, and seeing some of the changes you'd have to go back in time to Mass Effect 1 to see a different result for. It seems to be working out for Bioware so far! :)

Comment: I understand that the important choices, like who to let live or who to pact wiith can't be turned over. But since relationships have no real impact on the game, except for one or two cutscenes, it could be changeable..

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**romance article**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Mass_Effect_3) the only romances you can actually break up are ones you have previously romanced in either ME1 or ME2

For example, if you bed Ashley in ME1, then Miranda in ME2, then you will be given dialogue choices between the both of them and must decide which one you want to continue with, effectively breaking up with the other.  You also have the option of denying both of them and going for one of the newer ones like Cortez or Allers.

---

(note, answer written assuming male Shepard, see the above linked article for all possible romance options)